# Portainer create new volume

Tags: docker, portainer

I would like create new volume in `Portainer`. So, in Volumnes page and `Create Volume`, i want add my `/media/USBNAS` to `/media` container folder :

`Driver options
name : /media/USBNAS value : /media`

But i've an error message with `invalid option key: "/media/USBNAS"`

There is something I'm doing wrong, but I do not know what

Answer (score 4):

You will need the "local-persist" driver for this.

You can get it here: https://github.com/CWSpear/local-persist
Just install, if possible, using the install script and you're good to go.

Name **needs** to be "mountpoint" and value is your local path. As you setup your container, you can choose your created volume and set the container path.